# Objective-C background colour artifact under the border

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I want to create a rounded button like this one:

[image: preview 1]

using

```
UIButton *reportButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, -15, 30, 30)];

reportButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
reportButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
reportButton.layer.cornerRadius = reportButton.frame.size.width / 2;
reportButton.layer.borderColor = myRectangleBackgroundColor.CGColor;
```

but as you can see, there's a small 1px wide rounded line beneath the button.

You can see it better in this screenshot:

[image: preview 2]

How can I make it disappear?

Comment: This is aliasing. Not immediately sure how to fix it though.

Comment: @RileyAvron, That's not the problem. If it was anti-aliased, it still wouldn't make sense to be able to see the background colour beneath the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using two views. One green `UIView` of `30x30` and a white `UIButton` of `26x26` inside of it. It now looks like this:

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

1) Generate a circle and another overlaid circle in Core Graphics.

2) Create a UIImage from it.

3) Set it as a background image for various button states.

Comment: How to create a `UIImage` from it? Set what as a background image?

Comment: CoreGraphics -> Circle -> UIImage - >  UIbutton Background.